# How to validate int i ;;; in lex?

Tags: regex, lex

I am designing a lex that accepts simple c code, in which I want to put a rule that accepts multiple semicolons. I tried (;{2,}) & (;;+) but it is not accepting.

the statement lex is going to work on is

```
int i=1;
i=3*2;;;;
```

And I want to add regular expression to allow both statements. Because C validates ;;;;.

Comment: The 2 patterns that you offer require at least 2 semicolons.  Is that what you intended?  Perhaps you want to try `;+`?

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is allow only single semi colon and eliminate all other in the string like C compiler handles ;;;;;

Comment: Do this in your parser, not your lexer. Your parser should just accrpt an empty statement.

Comment: ya i added in my grammar and it worked. Thanks for your advice @rici.

Comment: I agree with the hints to accept an "empty" expression in the parser. But, out of curiosity, did you try `";"{2,}` also?

Comment: Please, see my answer. There is probably something else wrong. Consider, that another rule may match a longer sequence so that `;{2,}` is simply not selected e.g. something like `[^0-9A-Za-z_]+` which machtes also `\n`. Please, send a minimal complete sample. It's also worth to check the version of your lex/flex.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the OP. This is what I tried:

file `test-semicolon.l`:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%option noyywrap

%%

;{2,} printf("HERE->%s", yytext);
. ECHO;

%%

int main(int argc, char **argv) { yylex(); return 0; }
```

Compiled and tested with flex and gcc on cygwin:

```
$ flex -V 
flex 2.6.3

$ flex -otest-semicolon.c test-semicolon.l ; gcc -o test-semicolon test-semicolon.c
test-semicolon.c:398:0: warning: "yywrap" redefined

 ^
test-semicolon.c:74:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition

 ^

$ echo '
> 123
> 123;
> 123;;
> 123;;;
> 123;;;;
> int i=1;
> i=3*2;;;;
> ' | ./test-semicolon

123
123;
123HERE->;;
123HERE->;;;
123HERE->;;;;
int i=1;
i=3*2HERE->;;;;

$
```

The output shows that any sequence of two or more `;` is matched as expected.

Btw., lex and yacc sources for C are available at [ANSI C grammar, Lex specification](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html) and [ANSI C Yacc grammar](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html).

Also, I can recommend this book: [A Retargetable C Compiler: Design and Implementation](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=555424).